# Explicación de "?" en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo una pregunta, me explican que viene a ser esto de aqui?

`document.getelementbyid(parametro1).value ? document.getelementbyid(parametro1).value: "textoEjemplo";`

Gracias!

Comment: No es netamente de javascript. Buscá acerca de _operadores ternarios_ (es trabajar con `?` y `:` en conjunto).